# "How to fix 'Error: Invalid or missing identifier' in hyperledger composer"

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-composer

When I call a transaction named IntentForSale I get the 'Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type PropertyListing in namespace org.example.property'

I have tried to change let propertyListing = factory.newResource(propertynamespace, 'Property', tx.PID);
to let propertyListing = factory.newResource(propertynamespace, 'PropertyListing', tx.PID); and checked my model.cto.

Model.cto

```
/* This namespace helps in idetifying the entities for the network.    */
namespace org.example.property

/* Asset Property identified by a striing PID
This is used to maintain the properties which are registered in the system.
*/

asset Property identified by PID {
o String PID
o String owner
o Integer mktprice
o String RegistrationDate
o String PropertyType
o String Location
o String Status default = "Registered"
o Boolean Public
o Boolean Private
o Boolean IntentOfSale

}

/* Asset PropertyListing identified by a striing PLID
This is used to maintain the properties which are listed for sale in the system.
*/
asset PropertyListing identified by PLID {

o String PLID
o String owner
o Integer mktprice
o String RegistrationDate
o String PropertyType
o String Location
o String Status default = "Intent Of Sale"
}
```

```
    /* Participant Buyer identified by a striing Bname
This is used to maintain the buyers who are part of the system.
    */ 
    participant Buyer identified by Bname {
    o String Bname
    o String Bemail
    o Integer IdentityNo //Passport, SSN, Aadhar etc.
    o String Bnkname
    o String Bnkaddress
    o Integer AccNo
    o String IFSC
    o Integer Balance
    }

    /* Participant Seller identified by a striing Sname
    This is used to maintain the sellers who are part of the system.
    */ 
    participant Seller identified by Sname {
    o String Sname
    o String Semail
    o Integer IdentityNo
    o String Bnkname
    o String Bnkaddress
    o Integer AccNo
    o String IFSC
    o Integer Balance
    o String SaleDeedDocs
    }

    /* Participant Registrar identified by a striing Rname
    This is used to maintain the registrar who are part of the system.
    */ 
    participant Registrar identified by Rname {
    o String Rname 
    o String Remail
    }

    /* Transaction Created
    This is used to add new properties in the system.
    */ 
    transaction Created {
    o String PID
    --> Property cproperty
    }

    transaction Registered {
    o String PID
    --> PropertyListing rpropertylisting
    --> Buyer rbuyer
    }

    transaction IntentForSale {
    --> Property iproperty
    --> PropertyListing ipropertylisting
    --> Seller iseller  
    }
```

Script.js

```
    /**
    * Transaction Created to put the property for sale in the system
    * @param {org.example.property.IntentForSale} tx
    * @transaction
    */

    async function IntentForSale(tx){
    console.log('Property IntentForSale Transaction');

    //Getting the namespace and factory 
    const propertynamespace = 'org.example.property';
     const factory = getFactory();

    //Putting the property for sale
    let propertyListing = factory.newResource(propertynamespace,    'PropertyListing', tx.PLID);
    propertyListing.owner = tx.iseller.Sname;
    propertyListing.mktprice = tx.iproperty.mktprice;
    propertyListing.RegistrationDate = tx.iproperty.RegistrationDate;
    propertyListing.PropertyType = tx.iproperty.PropertyType;
    propertyListing.Location = tx.iproperty.Location;
    propertyListing.Status = tx.iproperty.Status;

    //Get the asset registry
    let registry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.property.PropertyListing');
    // save the property
    await registry.add(propertyListing);

    }
```

when I pass these

```
    {
    "$class": "org.example.property.IntentForSale",
    "iproperty": "resource:org.example.property.Property#101",
    "ipropertylisting": "resource:org.example.property.PropertyListing#102",
    "iseller": "resource:org.example.property.Seller#shantanu"
    }
```

[click to see error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGNux.png)
it should give transaction successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, in IntentForSale transcation model you don't have atributte PLID and you are passing this trough in transaction logic. I think that what you want to do create a new resource, you need to give some id to it. So is something like:

```
//Putting the property for sale
 let propertyListing = factory.newResource(propertynamespace, 'PropertyListing', tx.transactionId);
```

Comment: I am really new in this and learning the hyperledger. I tried everything else but did not pass PLID with ipropertylisting. Thankyou very much for the quick support.

Comment: I get it.

You need to generate the id or pass some number to it. 

Try this, should work:

//Putting the property for sale
    let propertyListing = factory.newResource(propertynamespace,    'PropertyListing', tx.transactionId);
    

this will get the id of transaction and pass as an id for this resource.